# Method called when dismissing a UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Is there a general best-practices way of being notified when the current view controller is being dismissed (either popped or dismissModalDialog'd)? I can't use -viewWillDisappear:, since that also gets called when another viewController is pushed atop the current one.

Comment: Note that iOS 5 provides the method `-isBeingDismissed`, which can be called inside `viewWillDisappear:` or `viewDidDisappear:`. But that doesn't help if you have to support earlier versions of iOS.

Comment: @KristopherJohnson's answer should be marked as the right answer these days now that iOS 4 is pretty much non-existent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"parentViewController" options:0 context:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([@"parentViewController" isEqualToString:keyPath] && object == self) {
        if (!self.parentViewController)
            NSLog(@"Dismissed");
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"parentViewController"];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this might not work as you expect if controller is "dismissed" as a result of one of its parents being dismissed. In this case, parentViewController will not be unset, but the dialog will still not be visible anymore. Really, "dismissed" should be better defined.

Answer (score 1):

Apple changed how presentation is working in iOS8, they are using presentationControllers, because presentationControllers are not KVO compilant, i had to use `containerView` because it is `removedFromSuperview` and nilled when `-[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:]` is called. Solution for iOS8 and above:

```
self.presentationContext.presentViewController(self.viewControllerToPresent, animated: true, completion: { _ in
     self.viewControllerToPresent.presentationController?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "containerView", options: [], context: &self.observingContext)
})
```

I am adding observer is completionHandler because presentation can fail sometimes especially when presenting on already presenting viewController.

In observer value i have to remove observation when containerView no longer exists:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    guard &self.observingContext == context else {
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
        return
    }
    if let presentationController = object as? UIPresentationController where presentationController.containerView == nil {
        presentationController.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "containerView")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no automatic way to get notified, but since UIViewController has a modalViewController property, you could define a like "didDismiss...", and call that method on the previous modal view controller after presenting your new modal view controller.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't do anything for standard, non-modal controllers, and it's fragile (it requires the parent to call it). I know there are ways around this, I'm just curious if there's an accepted 'best way to do it' out there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify you question?

I'm thinking that you're asking:

ViewcontrollerONE pops up ViewControllerTWO modally.
ViewControllerTWO is dismissed.
ViewControllerONE wants to know that That ViewControllerTWO just dismissed itself, and wants to run XYZ method because of it.

I don't have a good answer, but I do have a way:

VC1 is simply referenced in VC2. so VC2 can notify VC1 before dismissal.

Comment: No, ViewControllerTWO wants to know that IT was dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer using KVO did not work for me on iOS 8.

I subclassed UIViewController as follows and then I just call `dismissAnimated:completion:` on the presented view controller instead of `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`.  I register for observing the notification elsewhere and trigger handling as needed.

```
#define DismissNotifyViewControllerDismissedNotification  @"DismissNotifyViewControllerDismissed"


@interface DismissNotifyViewController : UIViewController

- (void)dismissAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion;

@end


@implementation DismissNotifyViewController

- (void)dismissAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated: flag
                                                      completion: ^{

          if (completion)
               completion();

          [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter 
                     postNotificationName: DismissNotifyViewControllerDismissedNotification
                     object: self];
    }];
}

@end
```